# About "pg_ctl promote" of PostgreSQL9.1

Tags: postgresql

Today I test the new feature about "replication features" of PostgreSQL9.1, 
First I have installed the Hot-standby of PostgreSQL9.1 successfully. It is not a problem。
What I want to test is that I want to use command "pg_ctl start promote " to active  standby node 
instead of creating a trigger file 。 Yes, after I execute the command, the standby node then becomes
primary and allow write/read operations。  But the initial primary node can not switchover to the 
standby role automatically. I am not sure If PostgreSQL9.1 is able to use "pg_ctl promote" do  switchover
between primary and standby node 。Can any body explain this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 'demote' option for [pg_ctl](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pg-ctl.html) - if the primary was cold when the standby was promoted perhaps it could be converted to a standby manually, but otherwise it will need a new base backup from the new primary.

The normal reason for switchover would be if the primary has failed so this would not be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, not the 'demote' , I mean "pg_ctl promote",  the url is the detail, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pg-ctl.html

Comment: I understand, but aren't you asking if there is a corresponding `demote` for the primary? AFAIK there is no automatic way of doing what you want.

Comment: thanks,anyway we can see that PostgreSQL9.1 is trying to make progress about Hot-Standby  Hope PostgreSQL 9.2 can switch over  automatlly ,may be just by a single commond.

Comment: I can't find it on the [todo list](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo) - you could try asking on the [mailing lists](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/) and suggesting the feature